# Is Raj still working with Sheldon?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

In Big Bang Theory season 3, Raj start working ***with*** Sheldon, or as Sheldon says working ***for*** him, and they fight over some desk size in office. However in later episodes it never shown whether Raj is working with Sheldon or not.

Currently I am watching season 6 and still it is not clear they are working together or not.

Answer (score 13):

In season 4, episode 4, Raj moves a desk into the office against Sheldon's will.

In season 5, episode 7, we see the two of them working together in the office. Sheldon puts a snake in Raj's drawer.

In season 5, episode 17, Sheldon moves into his new office, and Raj says, "I’m happy for you, Sheldon. But I have to admit I’m going to miss sharing an office with you."

I cannot see where it has been addressed in season 6 as yet, but one would have to presume it will be if the situation changes.

You can find transcripts of the episodes [here](http://bigbangtrans.wordpress.com/).

Comment: They still work together in Season 8 Episode 6 [The Expedition Approximation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3823240/). Sheldon and Raj test whether they could survive a dark-matter research expedition in a salt mine by simulating the conditions in a steam tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

Sheldon and Raj disagree on how to solve a work-related problem and Raj walks out. Sheldon actually apologizes at the end of the episode and he accepts that Raj was right but doesn't concede himself as being wrong. ***They agree to continue working together.***

**Source-** [Big Bang Theory(Season-3)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bang_Theory_%28season_3%29)

Also you will love to have a look at [Raj's biography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajesh_Koothrappali). It describes that *Raj definitely need some work to stay in the country.* If he would not have been working with Sheldon, he would be deported back to India.

Comment: That's just an extended summary of the episode. You completely ignored the op's question.

Comment: I have edited it to reflect the OP's question. hope it make sense now.